# How get commerce order total(excl vat, exlusive dicount), vat price, discount price, order total(incl vat and discount) in rules?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I am creating a rule on event "When checkout process is completed".
I want to send an email to the user when order completes.
In the email I want to send the following information

```
Order total price Exclusive discount and VAT
VAT price
Discount price
Order total Inclusive discount and VAT
```

But I don't see any token for these values. Only for the order total inclusive vat is available.

How will I display these values?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2063023) for this in the Commerce issue queue.

[This post here](https://drupalcommerce.org/questions/9046/add-tokens-commerce-order-token-types-commerce-order-total-field-components-base) describes what you'd need to do to add this to your site.